# How can I pass an object parameter to an event handler?

Tags: javascript, events

for example:

```
function getInfo(record){    //  record is an object
    ...
}
```

this function can be used by onclick event. However, when the browser parses it, it will be parsed as a string. So Firebug shows "missing ] after element list".

Can someone solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of when you click handler is generated/subscribed?

Comment: Yeah I'm still not sure what `record` is, or where is comes from. Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this:

```
somefunction = function(record)
{
    console.log('record: ' + record);
}

this.onclick = somefunction.bind(this, 100);
```

here 100 is argument you are passing to "somefunction", and it will print 100 on console.

I hope this will help.

html code can be something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> test page </title>
        <script>
            somefunction = function(record)
            {
                alert("record: " + record);
                var obj = eval('(' + record + ')');
                alert(" a:" + obj.a + " b: " + obj.b);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button1" 
               onclick="somefunction('{ a: 100, b: 200 }')">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think html can also be called in the same way. see the code when I click on the button it alerts for the record 100.

Comment: Thanks ,I mean the record is an object. it is not the string type, integer typ . it is a json type . such as :{name:'john',mail:'aa@aa.com'}

Comment: code adjusted for JSON object, I hope that is what you are asking. :)

Answer (score 1):

If Your's onclick is in HTML then try like this,

```
<input type="button"  onclick="getInfo(this)"  value="Click" />
```

You get the DOM Object

Comment: thanks, but I want to pass the record  to the getInfo functiong

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are so curious about object type, you can store your object in a separate variable.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> test page </title>
    <script>
        somefunction = function(record)
        {
            alert("record: " + record);
            var obj = eval('(' + record + ')');
            alert(" name:" + obj.name + " mail: " + obj.mail);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var myJSON = "{name:'john', mail:'aa@aa.com'}";
    </script>
    <input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button1" 
           onclick="somefunction(myJSON)">
</body>
```

Comment: Please accept as solution if answer matches your requirement. It'll help other users who are looking for same kind of problem.